# Facebook Registration on Google App Engine

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine

I have looked a bit into using the Facebook Registration for user authentication on my website and I am having trouble finding good examples.  I am using python on Google App Engine and wanted to see if anyone had examples that are not on facebook or in facebook canvas.  [This one](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/) is very helpful but doesn't have a few points I want to took at.

I just simply want to use Facebook as a way to allow users to log in and to be able to verify who they are on any page of my website.  Any examples of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ended up using SimpleAuth ( http://code.google.com/p/gae-simpleauth/ ) which has been a great solution and provided a lot of other options too

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to experiment more you could use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) which integrates nicely with Google App Engine and then on top of it by using the [Flask-OAuth](http://packages.python.org/Flask-OAuth/) the authentication part it's pretty straight forward ([full example](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth/blob/master/example/facebook.py)):

```
facebook = oauth.remote_app('facebook',
    base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_url='/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
    consumer_key=FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    consumer_secret=FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    request_token_params={'scope': 'email'}
)
```

[gae-init](http://gae-init.appspot.com/) is one of my examples where I'm using Flask on Google App Engine and you could login using Facebook or Twitter besides the Google login.

Comment: would flask work alright along with Jinja2 and webapp2?  What you have on GAE-Init is exactly what I would like to allow users to login

Comment: @clifgray GAE-Init uses jinja2 so there is no problem there.. if you go through flask documentation and spend a little bit more time with it on gae.. you will eventually stop the traditional webapp2 url mapping and handling.. it's so much easier..! :)

Comment: @clifgray for example check this file: http://code.google.com/p/gae-init/source/browse/main/main.py where you have the URK mappings and request handlers kind of connected and not in separate files, once your project will become bigger as it would happen with the traditional webapp2 approach..

Comment: alright neat I'll check it out. it looks great.  also do you think this will be supported and developed further for a bit to come?

Answer (score 1):

This (unofficial) Facebook SDK for Python fork has a suite of examples, including one for App Engine.

https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/tree/master/examples/appengine

(Note: not tested recently, nor warranted by me or Facebook. But could help.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not in terse example format, but here is working code that supports registration and login through facebook:

https://github.com/mjibson/journalr/blob/master/main.py (search for "facebook")
https://github.com/mjibson/journalr/blob/master/facebook.py (just a simple module that implements the facebook API and isn't the full SDK)